# Can we remove the Jquery version comment in plugin

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery version 2.2.4. I need to remove jQuery version(first line) from a jQuery plugin. Are there any license issues if i removethis, or can we simply remove it?

[image]

Comment: Can we ask why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [license](https://jquery.org/license/) you will see it states *You are free to use the Project in any other project (even commercial projects) as long as the copyright header is left intact.*. Therefore, you should keep it there.